# If $a,b,c,d>0$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$, will $\frac{a}{c}<\frac{b}{d}$ hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Hi everyone and merry Christmas.

I'm trying to prove something in metric spaces and I got to a point where I have something like $a<b$ and $c<d$ with all $a,b,c,d>0$, then I concluded that $$\frac{a}{c}<\frac{b}{d}$$
which makes it work for the problem.

How accurate is my assumption? If anything is taking for granted or assumed wrongly, can someone help please. Thank you.

Comment: $a=c=1$, $b=d=2$

Comment: Shouldn’t this be tagged Algebra-precalculus?

Comment: Does it mean it a right assumption

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 1 2 = \frac {10} {20}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note that as $a, b, c, d >0$, $$ a< b \implies ad < bd$$ and $$c < d \implies bc < bd$$

But, there is insufficient information to conclude that $ad < bc$, or, in other words, $\frac{a}{c}<\frac{b}{d}$.

Answer (score 0):

> I have something like $a<b$ and $c<d$ with all $a,b,c,d>0$, then I concluded that $$\frac{a}{c}<\frac{b}{d}$$

If that were to hold true, then you could use it to prove the following next:

> I have something like $\color{red}{c<d}$ and $\color{red}{a<b}$ with all $a,b,c,d>0$, then I concluded that $$\frac{\color{red}{c}}{\color{red}{a}}<\frac{\color{red}{d}}{\color{red}{b}}$$

But the two propositions are contradictory, so $\;\ldots$

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!